# Json installation on linux web hosting server

Tags: javascript, php, json, hosting, web-hosting

I want to use JSON plugins on my linux hosting server. How can I install? I am a beginner. Your help will be much appreciable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As of PHP 5.2.0, the JSON extension is bundled and compiled into PHP by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON by default in recent PHP versions (5.2+):
http://php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php

You do not need to install anything else.